# How to prevent others create a new instance of a class on heap?

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent a class from being allocated via the 'new' operator? (I'd like to ensure my RAII class is always allocated on the stack.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124856/how-do-i-prevent-a-class-from-being-allocated-via-the-new-operator-id-like)

Suppose I define a class in the library

```
class Base {};
```

and I publish the class to the users.

And one user defines a new class

```
class Derived : public Base {}
```

The question what can I do in `Base` to prevent users create an instance of `Derived` on heap?

For example, this is allowed

```
Derived dd;
```

This is not

```
Derived* dd = new Derived();
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think you can make the new operator private.

Comment: @Greg: You probably mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124856/how-do-i-prevent-a-class-from-being-allocated-via-the-new-operator-id-like).

Comment: @Greg -I believe that question you linked is infact, the exact opposite of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Perception Whoops, my mistake.

Comment: @user315052 Surely that only prevents the creation of `Base` objects on the heap, and doesn't affect `Derived` objects at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to declare a `private` `operator new` (I can't recall if this is needed but you'll probably want to do all three: normal, array, and placement) in your base class. The user can still get around this by creating their own `operator new` in the Derived class but at least they have to think about it and actively work to subvert your intention.

If you're worried about non-accidental problems with creating your class on the heap (for example malicious developers of child classes), C++ is not the language for this project. It's powerful and has lots of places where your have to rely on your end-programmers not bypassing the intentions.

Answer (score 4):

You make `operator new` private in the base class.

```
class Base {
    void* operator new(size_t);
};
class Derived : public Base {
}

//...

Base* p = new Derived; //ERROR
Derived d;             //OK
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making the `new` operator private in `Base`, you can give a reminder to the user of `Base` what the intention of `Base` is. This way, a developer using `Base` can't claim the intentions were not documented.

```
class Base
{
    void * operator new (size_t) {}
    void * operator new[] (size_t) {}
    void * operator new (size_t, void *) {}
protected:
    struct I_promise_not_to_dynamically_allocate_Base {};
    Base (I_promise_not_to_dynamically_allocate_Base) {}
    virtual ~Base () {}
    //...
};
```

Now, when the developer uses the `Base`, they are forced to pass in the argument:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived () : Base(I_promise_not_to_dynamically_allocate_Base()) {}
    //...
};
```

As already stated, nothing prevents the the developer from overloading `new` and `delete` themselves, but then they would be breaking a promise!