# C++: Should a tree root use inheritance over composition?

Tags: c++, inheritance, tree, composition

I have a tree-like data structure that I've set up like this:

```
class Root; // forward declaration

class Tree {
public:
    void addChildren(Root &r, ...) { childA = r.nodeSpace.allocate(); ... }
    // tons of useful recursive functions here
private:
    Tree *childA, *childB, *childC;
    Tree *parent;
    int usefulInt;
};

class Root : public Tree {
    friend class Tree; // so it can access our storage
public:

private:
    MemoryPool<Tree> nodeSpace;
};
```

I really like this structure, because

1. I can call all the recursive functions defined on `Tree` on `Root` as well, without having to copy-paste them over.
2. Root owns the storage, so whenever it passes out of scope, that's how I define the tree as no longer being valid.

But then I realized a problem. Someone might inadvertently call

```
Tree *root = new Root();

delete root; // memory leak! Tree has no virtual destructor...
```

This is not an intended usage (any ordinary usage should have `Root` on the stack). But I am open to alternatives. Right now, to solve this, I have three proposals:

- Add virtual destructor to `Tree`. I would prefer not doing this because of the overhead as the tree can have many, many nodes.
- Do not let `Root` inherit from `Tree` but instead have it define its own `Tree` member. Creates a little indirection, not too terrible, can still call the tons of useful recursive functions in `Tree` by doing `root.tree().recursive()`.
- Forbid assignments like `Tree *root = new Root();`. I have no idea if this is even possible or discouraged or encouraged. Are there compiler constructs?
- Something else?

Which one of these should I prefer? Thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding option #3, looks like it's possible as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124856/how-do-i-prevent-a-class-from-being-allocated-via-the-new-operator-id-like

Answer (score 0):

The root node class (or any other node class) should not be an interface class. Keep it `private` and then inheritance without dynamic polymorphism (`virtual`) is not dangerous because the user will never see it.

> Forbid assignments like `Tree *root = new Root();`. I have no idea if this is even possible or discouraged or encouraged. Are there compiler constructs?

This would be done by having `Root` inherit from `Tree` as a private base class.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I'm confused. What should I keep `private`: do you mean

`class Root : private Tree` ?

Comment: My first suggestion is to have `Root` and `Node` both as hidden implementation details and define other classes to handle the interface. Then I point out that `class Root : private Tree` is an easier solution toward another direction that you have mentioned.

Comment: I see, thanks! I read on some random website "Private inheritance means is-implemented-in-terms-of. It's usually inferior to composition". Would you advise using the composition proposal above over the private inheritance option?

Comment: @bombax You can choose among several steps on the convenience vs. quality scale. The best quality is to define one set of classes for implementation/in-memory storage, and hide them from the user, and another set of classes for interface/data access. The best convenience is whatever is convenient. Composition is a good step in the quality direction, but a small step.